# JavaScript redirecting does not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have tried inserting each of these in a JavaScript function on a webpage, and they all work when the page is viewed on a PC, but none of them work when the function is used on my phone (Sony Ericsson Xperia, if that matters):

```
window.location = [the url goes here];

window.location.href = [the url goes here];

window.location.assign([the url goes here]);

document.location = [the url goes here];

document.location.href = [the url goes here];
```

I tested that the function is activated (with an alert() in the function that shows both on PC and mobile), but the page is never redirected on mobile, it just remains unchanged. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: what is the actual code? did you test in different mobile browsers ?

Comment: @Fast Snail: That is the actual code. The function header ("function go(gourl){") and that (plus the end }, of course). I tried it with each of the versions listed. The rest of the code has nothing to do with thise function. You can see my upload test here: http://www.limedark.com/Favriz/display.php

Comment: And I only tested it on my phone. As soon as it failed there, I assumed there was a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code, which is valid, on my Xiaomi Mi Rednote 2 running Firefox, and it works just fine.  I suspect your phone's browser is not set correctly to run JavaScript.

[Xperia Z browser setup](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-28251#steps4)

Comment: It has never happened before. Is there something very unique in that tiny bit of code that I should be aware of?

Comment: @HenryStone : no, nothing unique there at all. How about adding another browser to your phone; Opera or Firefox for instance, and then trying it out. There is possibly a security application on the phone which is also blocking pop-ups.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to fix the server side problem for my website, but I just picked a different approach.